# Printing Kable and ggplot within for loop causes ggplot to overlap Kable in R Markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I want to print a table and plot for each element (product group) in my data, and this will be on a separate tab for each product group. E.g.

```
for(i in prod) {
cat('\n')
cat('### ', paste(i), '\n')
print(Kable)

cat('\n')

print(ggplot)

cat('\n')
}
```

Except this causes the ggplot to be plotted on top of my table.

Comment: try using `cat"\n\n")` - two line returns gives a new paragraph

Comment: Nope doesn't work for me

Comment: What type of document output? pdf? html? What do you mean by tab?